# UE4.27.2 unable to build for the quest 1 but able to do it in UE5.3.2

Tags: java, android, sdk, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Using the same project on both versions 5.3 and 4.27 able to successfully build as well on both but..The apk built in 4.27 does not run on the quest 1 it goes into loading with a black screen then crashes, I've added quest 1 to the list in the project settings in 4.27, 5.3 has an option for "build to meta quest devices" instead of this list which is in 4.27, It works when built with 5.3 but not 4.27, Please help!

Tried building apk on both version works with 5.3 but not 4.27

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.